# Foundation 3 - dropdown menu pushes down page, how to prevent this?

Tags: css

I'm building a responsive site using Foundation 3 and I've got a dropdown menu that when at smaller screen sizes is pushing down the content rather than overlaying the content below. I'm not sure why this is happening or what I may have done to cause this.

The site in question is [here](http://blue.bcwebinc.com/~minerals/). There's a couple of other issues with the site, but this is the one that's got me really flummoxed.

What is the best way to fix it so the drop down is not pushing down the rest of the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you were looking for a solution specific to your framework but here are the changes I made to do what you requested.

```
.nav-bar.right {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
  background-color:#fff;
  top:5px;
  border:2px solid #ccc;
  border-top-width:0px;
}

.top-bar.expanded {
  overflow:visible;
}
```

Seems to work pretty well (I only tested in Chrome 26). Feel free to tweak as you need!

Answer (score 1):

For Foundation 5 i just created this hack for myself figured id share it.

```
.top-bar.expanded {
    overflow:visible;
}
.top-bar-section ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-options="scrolltop: false">
```

or on initialization:

```
$(document).foundation('topbar', {scrolltop: false});
```

To stop all that horrible jumping